# Sonarqube docker container fails to restart, offline

Tags: docker, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Background: I have a system behind a proxy/firewall.  I can access docker to pull images, but do not have a username/password to access any other sites.  Therefore my docker container of sonarqube is essentially offline.

Question: The docker container starts fine the first time, but fails to restart.  This happens in two instances, either a manually installed plugin presents an error that it fails to download the update-center url, or it simply starts shutting down immediately as it starts.  Both fail the application which closes the container. I do not seem to be able (or understand how to) modify the sonar.properties to get the update-center disabled and need guidance.

I have inquired on the github for the container without much help: https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/76#issuecomment-364563967  The '-Dsonar.updatecenter.activate=false' option does not work when I try it.

Simply shutting down

```
2018.02.09 21:45:38 INFO  ce[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting ce
2018.02.09 21:45:38 INFO  ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine starting     up...
2018.02.09 21:45:39 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.02.09 21:45:39 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin     [org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.ReindexPlugin]
2018.02.09 21:45:39 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin     [org.elasticsearch.join.ParentJoinPlugin]
2018.02.09 21:45:39 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin     [org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorPlugin]
2018.02.09 21:45:39 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.02.09 21:45:41 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2018.02.09 21:45:41 INFO  ce[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://pgsonar:5432/sonar
2018.02.09 21:45:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: /opt/sonarqube
2018.02.09 21:45:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Load plugins
2018.02.09 21:45:45 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.q.PurgeCeActivities] Delete the Compute Engine tasks created before Sun Aug 13 21:45:45 UTC 2017
2018.02.09 21:45:45 INFO  ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine is operational
2018.02.09 21:45:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ce] is up
2018.02.09 21:45:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is up
2018.02.09 21:47:12 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Stopping SonarQube
2018.02.09 21:47:13 INFO  ce[][o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process
2018.02.09 21:47:13 INFO  ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine is stopping...
2018.02.09 21:47:13 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.t.CeProcessingSchedulerImpl] Waiting for workers to finish in-progress tasks
2018.02.09 21:47:14 INFO  ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine is stopped
2018.02.09 21:47:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [ce] is stopped
2018.02.09 21:47:15 INFO  web[][o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process
2018.02.09 21:47:18 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2018.02.09 21:47:18 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2018.02.09 21:47:18 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
2018.02.09 21:47:18 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143
chown: cannot access '/opt/sonarqube/temp/README.txt': No such file or directory
```

Will update with the fail to download later (no access to logs at this exact moment)

Comment: Has the user starting SonarQube read/write rights on the SonarQube folder? What about the "cannot access" message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the README.txt issue, you have to create a volume and mount the temp folder (note that I use the postgres setup from [anorak:girl](http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2015/11/super-quick-sonarpostgres-setup-with-docker/)). You can then start and stop with no problems.

```
sudo docker volume create sonarqube-temp
sudo docker run -d --name sonarqube --link sonar-postgres:pgsonar -p 9000:9000 -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD='secure'  -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://pgsonar:5432/sonar -v sonarqube-temp:/opt/sonarqube/temp sonarqube:lts
```

Regarding the UpdateCenter issue, workaround is to specify a configuration with the run command (this is specific to Godin's docker container for sonarqube - through his run.sh script):

```
sudo docker run -d --name sonarqube --link sonar-postgres:pgsonar -p 9000:9000 -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD='secure'  -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://pgsonar:5432/sonar -v sonarqube-temp:/opt/sonarqube/temp sonarqube:lts -Dsonar.updatecenter.activate=false
```